# configure standalone SDK for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I use `Ubuntu 14.04` and am trying to installed `Android Studio 1.5`. Before I had downloaded full Android SDK and it is available by running `android` in terminal (SDK/tools is part of environmental path).

When I try to install Android studio, it wants to install Android SDK in another path and when I select `custom` installation, I cannot remove check mark of installation of SDK in `SDK Components Setup` form.

[image]

Now I canceled that and try to use `Welcome to Android Studio >> configure >> SDK manager | Settings >> appearance and behavior >> system settings >> Android SDK`:

[image]

But `Launch standalone SDK manager` does not work and `Edit` (Android SDK Location) returns to `SDK Components Setup` form again.

Is there a way to configure available SDK to Android Studio?

Comment: I see the Android SDK path as editable in File > Project Structure, in the "SDK Location" category (or whatever the term is for the column of headings on the left).

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you mean I have to install new SDK by that wizard and then change the path and delete new SDK directory?

Comment: No, you should be able to just fill in your directory in the File > Project Structure dialog. I run Ubuntu and that Android SDK directory field is editable for me. Moreover, I too have the Android SDK installed in an unusual location, and Android Studio is happy with the value that I have provided it. Note that I am running Android Studio 1.5.1, in case you're on a different version.

Comment: @CommonsWare Version of my Android Studio is `1.5`.

Comment: In the "Android Studio Setup Wizard" (the first screen shot), can you edit the "Android SDK Location" field?

Comment: Also, are you trying to use the SDK which you previously downloaded or are you trying to download a fresh version?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No it is not editable.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I used that previously ... .

Comment: @hasanghaforian There is a button with "..." to the right of the box with the SDK path. What happens when you click it?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice OK! I browse to old SDK path and wizard detect existing Android SDK. Please add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use your original SDK installation directory, either edit it manually in the setup wizard or click the "..." button to navigate to it.