# Rendering problems: No android SDK found. Please configure an android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, render

I just installed android studio 1.5.1. Unfortunately the android layout monitor won't render and it's giving me this error message "Rendering problems: No android SDK found. Please configure an android SDK" 
I updated all my android SDK's and it gave it correct location yet it still won't render. What should I do? 
Thanks in advance.
[My android studio with the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qChPl.png)

Comment: Would really help if you can provide more info. Can you post a screenshot of what is showing, and a screenshot of the ***Standalone SDK Manager***.

Comment: I posted the android studio screenshot. I don't have a standalone sdk manager. I was using the one inside android studio.

Comment: Try right-clicking the Android Studio icon and selecting "Run as administrator".

Comment: No Standalone? :O It usually comes along with Android Studio. ***SDK Manager > Android SDK > Launch Standalone SDK Manager*** -- You can see it just on the lower part of the 2nd screenshot in this post -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208523/configure-standalone-sdk-for-android-studio

Comment: checkout the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613444/select-target-api-in-the-android-studio-layout-design-preview